# why doesn't this block of text center vertically, just one line?

Tags: css, html

http://tinkerbin.com/ojXJuQfl

i managed to use instructions from another user and centered text vertically, but it doesn't allow me to center the whole thing vertically. i figured if i put the text in it's own div, it would do it, but it didn't. how can i center a PARAGRAPH next to the arrow?

vertical aligning CSS is very confusing...

CSS

```
#arrow {
       width:33px;
       height:25px;
       background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/26tbf.png');
       margin-left:55px;
       background-position:0 50%;
       float:left;
       height:100%;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
 } 

#bulletwrap {
       border:1px solid black;
       width:325px;
       height:75px;
 } 

#text {
      background-position:0 50%;
      line-height:75px;    
 }
```

HTML

```
<div id="bulletwrap"><div id="arrow"></div><div id="text">This is some longer text that needs to be centered next to the arrow grouped together</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertical centering something can be rather difficult. I have an alternate proposal to your solution. It is a bit of a hacky solution, but as far as I know it's the best and most effective.

You will need to have your #bulletwrap div (or any other container type element) behave as a table, and your #text (paragraph or div, it doesn't matter) as a table cell. This will allow you to use `vertical-align: middle;` for the #text element, centering it vertically.

This is the important css:

```
#bulletwrap {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:325px;
  height:75px;
  display: table; /*set your container to behave as table*/
} 

#text {
  display: table-cell; /*set your text to behave as table cell*/
  vertical-align: middle; /*... and vertically align it*/
}
```

Here it is in action http://tinkerbin.com/jSocLUGX

I hope that was clear enough. If you have any further questions or feel your question was not really answered, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: i still use this as a reference all the time.. thanks again for this answer lol.. one year later...

Comment: Glad I could be of help :).

Answer (score 2):

[here is my version](http://tinkerbin.com/RRICo4zr) I used `display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle; height: whatever;` on the text `div` and `display: table` on the bulletwrap `div`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason the arrow has to be in a `div`? Usually the easiest way to vertically-align an image is to [use it as a background](http://tinkerbin.com/RVoZZLtL).

```
<div id="bulletwrap">
  <div id="text">
    This is some longer text that needs to be centered next to the arrow grouped together and what happens if there is even more text then that is not going to work out so well
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#bulletwrap {
       border:1px solid black;
       width:325px;
       background:url('http://i.imgur.com/26tbf.png') no-repeat left center;
       padding: 10px 0 10px 35px
 }
```

Note - to center the text, I just made the padding the same for the top and bottom. Actually you should apply the padding to the container. This also allows the box to expand with the text, though you may not desire that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

line-height:75px; is the culprit.  line-height will apply to each line in the wrapped text, not the entire "block" of text.  Probably best to use radixhound's solution or a margin/padding approach possibly.